# Double Exponential Smoothing (DES) yields different results in R and Python?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, time-series

I am finding different results for ETS AAN method in R and python.  Any reason?

### R code

```
> x
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2016  36  78  35 244  25 283  42   6  59   5  47  20
2017   0   0   5  38  16 143  14  37  60   2  55   0
> fit <- forecast::ets(x,model="AAN")
> forecast::forecast(fit, h=h)

           Point Forecast     Lo 80   Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 3  -->        2.006235 -93.95293 97.9654 -144.7506 148.7631
```

### Python

```
> import statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters as ets
> holt_r = ets.ExponentialSmoothing(dft, trend='additive', damped=False, seasonal=None).fit()
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:171: ValueWarning: No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency M will be used.

  % freq, ValueWarning)

> holt_r.forecast(1)

Out[39]: 
2018-01-31 --->   13.049129

Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please *format you code appropriately!*

Comment: can we please have a **reproducible** example?

Answer (score 0):

R and Python use different optimizers to find the values for the final parameters (alpha and beta) of the model, so they're not always going to give the same results. You should look in the documentation and see which optimizations methods are being used.